# OnPropertyChanged not firing when combobox first item is selected in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, combobox

I have a combobox in a WPF gridview like so:

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Type" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={my:EnumValues {x:Type my:CommandTypes}}}" 
                                        MinWidth="100"/>
```

And a ViewModel behind it like this:

```
public class LoadSimCommand {
    public CommandTypes Type
    {
        get
        {
            return mType;
        }
        set
        {
            mType = value;
            switch (mType)
            {
                /* Set some dependency properties */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works well except for one case: when I click on the combobox and select the first item from the list, the ViewModel is not updated. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As I was typing the question I thought of the answer. I still wanted to share the solution in case someone else is experiencing the same issue. The ViewModel is not updating because the ViewModel's CommandTypes property deafult value is 0 which translates to the first value in the enumeration. Therefore, when the first item is selected, the property isn't changed and therefore OnPropertyChanged is not fired because the property hasn't changed.

Now, I don't want to introduce an additional CommandType just to cover this so I decided to trick my datatype and make it Nullable like so:

```
public CommandTypes? Type;
```

Now the initial value of the Type is null and I can use `value.HasValue` to do some sanity testing. I also changed the initial states of the dependency properties I want to set in the `switch` to a "invalid" value so that my UI state is still consistent.

As a final step I added a RowEditEnding event handler with the following content:

```
private void DataGridView_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the entered type is not null
    if (!(e.Row.Item is LoadSimCommand) || 
         (e.Row.Item as LoadSimCommand).Type == null)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

That way the row is not committed when the proper row type is not set.

Hope this is of some use to someone!